# extract archived .bz2 files inside a .tar archive with a single command

Tags: linux, tar, pipe, bzip2

i need to decompress .bz2 files inside a .tar archive (two step decompression)

For example:

> requested_files_1.tar

has multiple .bz2 files inside.

How can I extract them with a single command in linux. I have tried this  but it does n't work.

> tar -xvf requested_files_1.tar | bzip2 -d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipe doesn't work because tar isn't extracting the files to stdout, it's just listing them. bzip2 therefore tries to decompress the list of filenames as **plain text**, which of course, is not a compressed file's contents (i.e., it's using the plain text as the contents of the file to be extracted).

In order to use the output from `tar xvf` as a list of **filenames** for `bzip2` to extract, you can do the following:

```
bzip2 -d $(tar xvf requested_files_1.tar)
```

The `v` option for `tar` here is required to list the extracted files for bzip2.

Comment: This is the perfect and most efficient piece of code. It worked flawlessly. it was even better when I put a for loop inside the parenthesis and made it to run for all the tar files in that directory. thanks again.
>bzip2 -d $(for i in *.tar;do tar xvf $i;done)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a duplicate of

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files

So your script would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in `ls *.tar` ; do
    dir="${f%.*}"
    mkdir "$dir"
    cd $dir
    tar -xf "../$f"
    bunzip2 *.bz2
    cd ..
done
```